# Navigating to a page inside it()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

Protractor style guide [recommends](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#navigate-to-the-page-under-test-before-each-test) against navigating to a page inside `it()` explaining the motivation the following way:

> Why? - Assures you that the page under test is in a clean state

I'm not sure I completely understand the motivation.

What does the *clean state* mean in this context? *What can go wrong* if `browser.get()` is put into `it()` instead of `beforeEach()` or `beforeAll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main focus of their advice is reloading before *each* test, rather than whether it's loaded in beforeEach or within the 'it' block.

Comment: Navigating in 'beforeEach' would be ok, or even at the beginning of an 'it' block. But if you have the same navigation in every 'it' then it should be refactored up to the beforeEach anyway. You just have to realize the 'it' blocks will run one after the other, and it is a better practice to make each test standalone rather than depend on the state of a previous test.